# How to use a second type of the same letter in an Font file (.otf)

Tags: android, kotlin, fonts

So in my .otf file for my font, apparently there is 2 types of the letter 'a' and by default its using the wrong one.
I was wondering how to use the second type of 'a' in the .otf file in Android / Kotlin.

Comment: That depends entirely on what you mean with "the second type" because that's not font terminology. There are lots of different mechanisms by which an OpenType font (ttf/otf/svg/doesn't matter, any opentype flavour) can be instructed to use an alternate glyph, e.g.  it could be a stylistic set, it could be a historical equivalent, it could be a ligature (unlkely or single glyphs of course), it could be an alternate used when the actual script the font is being asked to shape is different (e.g. latin `(` vs cjk `（`), etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, after reading what you said, I look a lot more into, sadly I still cant figure everything out.
 But now I know that in my otf file, there is something called Opentype Features, and the one that I need to change is SS01
 Right now, this feature is set in Latin, but I need it in Cyrillic.
 
 I saw that in my xml file I can have acces to (android:fontVariationSettings="")
 but I'm not sure if its the right way to do it and I cant fint what to actually put as parameters.

Comment: @TracyNguyen Some parts of your question aren't clear. Are you trying to create a font, or just using a font someone else created in your app? Also, you mentioned "2 types of the letter 'a'", but in your later comment you said, "this feature is set in Latin, but I need it in Cyrllic". Well, the letter 'a' that you cited is U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A, not a Cyrillic letter. So that part of your question also isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, you're asking about Stylistic Sets (SS01 in particular), which is a standard OpenType feature that can be toggled with [setFontFeatureSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFontFeatureSettings(java.lang.String)), using the string format explained over on the [CSS Fonts Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-feature-settings-prop).

However, OpenType features are usually "per script", so you'll want to verify that SS01 even does anything for Cyrillic.

Comment: If you want to apply a Stylistic Set substitution for Cyrillic characters, what 'Pomax' has said is correct: it's possible the font doesn't have 'ss01' substitutions for Cyrillic characters. But, if a font _does_ have substitutions for Cyrillic characters, and you're just trying to figure out how to access those alternate glyphs in your app, then the fact that they are Cyrillic characters rather than Latin doesn't matter to you: that's all handled internally between the font and the text layout engine.